# Issues when swapping columns in the Rotate Matrix exercise (codefights)

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to solve the problem of rotating a matrix by 90 degrees. Here is my solution so far:

```
static int[][] rotateImage(int[][] a) {

      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                int temp_ji = a[j][i];
                a[j][i] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = temp_ji;
            }
        }

      int columnA = 0;
      int columnB = a.length-1;

      while(columnA != columnB)
      {
          swapColumns(a, columnA, columnB);
          columnA++; columnB--;
          if(columnA == 10)
          {
              break;
          }
      }

    return a;
}

static void swapColumns(int a[][], int cA, int cB)
{
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int temp_ij = a[i][cB];
        a[i][cB] = a[i][cA];
        a[i][cA] = temp_ij;
        s = s + " " + a[i][cA];
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting why my code is not swapping the columns correctly when I have this entry:

```
int a[][] = new int[][]{

     {40,12,15,37,33,11,45,13,25,3}, 
     {37,35,15,43,23,12,22,29,46,43}, 
     {44,19,15,12,30,2,45,7,47,6}, 
     {48,4,40,10,16,22,18,36,27,48}, 
     {45,17,36,28,47,46,8,4,17,3}, 
     {14,9,33,1,6,31,7,38,25,17}, 
     {31,9,17,11,29,42,38,10,48,6}, 
     {12,13,42,3,47,24,28,22,3,47}, 
     {38,23,26,3,23,27,14,40,15,22}, 
     {8,46,20,21,35,4,36,18,32,3}

    };

    a = rotateImage(a);
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

This is the original formulation of the problem:

> You are given an n x n 2D matrix that represents an image. Rotate the image by 90 degrees (clockwise).

Example

For

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

the output should be

```
rotateImage(a) =
    [[7, 4, 1],
     [8, 5, 2],
     [9, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This is the correct while condition:

```
      int counter = 0;
      while(counter < (a.length / 2))
      {
          swapColumns(a, columnA, columnB);
          columnA++; columnB--;
          counter++;
      }
```